# Numerical equation, consistency condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I have a trivial question about [Ralston's book](http://62.182.86.140/main/798000/0f9244b182926b419e73dbba1d249950/Anthony%20Ralston%2C%20Philip%20Rabinowitz%20-%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Numerical%20Analysis%2C%20Second%20Edition-Dover%20Publications%20%282001%29.djvu) (If after clicking on the link the download doesn't start, copy the link and paste it in the browser's tab.)

I do not follow how can I obtain from $(5.2-5)$ by inserting into it $y_i=x_i^j,j=1$
the second equation in $(5.2-6)$ (with $h$=1):

$$1=-\sum_{i=0}^p ia_i+\sum_{i=-1}^p b_i,j=1$$.

If I take $y_i=y_{n+1}=x$ I obtain $$x=-\sum_{i=0}^p a_i x+\sum_{i=-1}^p b_i\cdot 1,j=1$$ but at the same time if I take $y_i=y_{n+1}=1$ I obtain $$1=-\sum_{i=0}^p a_i \cdot 1+\sum_{i=-1}^p b_i\cdot 0,j=1.$$

None of these two equations resemble the second equation in $(5.2-6),j=1.$

**Snippets from the book:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful when inserting, you want
$$
x_{n+1}^j=\sum_{i=0}^{p}a_i(x_{n-i})^j+h\sum_{i=-1}^pb_i j(x_{n-i})^{j-1}
$$
at $n=0$ and with $x_i=ih$.

Comment: Your $x_i=i\cdot h=i$ where $h=1$ should read $x_{n-i}=-i$, is that correct ? You have $x_n=0$, $x_{n-1}=0-1$, $x_{n-2}=-2$ etc.

Comment: That is not necessary. The powers of $h$ cancel.

Comment: But it should be the case that $h>0$.

Comment: The resulting condition is independent of $h$. The cancellation is valid for any $h\ne 0$, making $h$ negative just changes the integration direction.